# Erro ao tentar adicionar uma coluna do tipo double no mysqli

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Preciso adicionar algumas colunas a minha banco do `mysqli` que segundo o `wamp` é a versão ***5.7.26*** pois estou fazendo a integração com mercado pago, porém, percebo que independente da forma que eu crio minha table, logo depois de adicionar a coluna 'data' do tipo date, recebo o seguinte ***erro***:

> 1064 - você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ') NOT NULL AFTER `data` na linha 1.

E o comando indicado que aponta este erro é o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE `fatura`  ADD `valor` DOUBLE(255) NOT NULL  AFTER `data`;
```

Estou usando a interface gráfica para adicionar colunas, não entendo como pode ser possível que ocorra um erro por digitação de comandos SQL, como se eu estivesse os executando de forma manual

Aqui esta meu SQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fatura`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fatura` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `forma` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE fatura ADD valor DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER data;` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWnCukrctrWnAnhiggS3vi/0

Comment: obrigado, deu certinho :)